# Virtual Box, virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-11.10

How to reduce the size of a Dynamically expanding virtual machine,
I have a Windows Xp host machine and a Ubuntu 11.10 guest virtual machine whose maximum size is 8GB which is getting maxed out i dont want to resize the .vdi file , data in the virtual machine is about 3 GB but when we delete some files  it does not free space in virtual machine.

Virtual box version 4.1.8
Windows Xp host
Ubuntu 11.10 guest

Comment: this isn't a programming related question, flagged to there: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the virtual machine:

1. defragment
2. zero the free space with http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443 sdelete

Outside the virtual machine

1. VBoxManage modifyhd Disk.vdi --compact